# How can I reset all the bind keys in my Bash?

Tags: bash, keyboard-shortcuts

I bound some keys by mistake, and they don't work any more, such as <kbd>HOME</kbd>, <kbd>END</kbd>, <kbd>UP</kbd>, <kbd>DOWN</kbd>, <kbd>LEFT</kbd>, <kbd>RIGHT</kbd>.

Is there a way to reset all the bound keys to their original state?

Comment: Its usually defined in your `.inputrc`.

Comment: there is nothing in my .inputrc, and /etc/inputrc only defines some of them. So i wonder where all these r defined?

Answer (score 6):

If it's bash that you misconfigured, you might have done so either in `~/inputrc` or in `~/.bashrc`. `~/.inputrc` is the configuration file for the [readline library](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Readline), which is used by bash and a few other command-line programs to read input. `~/.bashrc` is the configuration file of bash itself.

If you start a shell with `bash --norc`, your `~/.bashrc` isn't read, but your `~/.inputrc` is. If you start a shell with `HOME=/none bash`, neither file is read, nor your previous shell history.

Answer (score 4):

You can reset bash key bindings to their original state:
`set -o emacs`

This sets all key bindings to the default (which is emacs key bindings).
Alternatively, if you prefer, you can do:
`set -o vi`

You can also use `bind -r <keycode>` to remove a single key binding.

More details can be found in the bash man page under "SHELL BUILTIN COMMANDS", then look for "set" and also "bind".

Comment: use 'bind -r <keycode>' if you can't type the key. http://keycode.info

Comment: ..and use * in place of a single key if you can't even type a key needed to edit .bashrc or type the above command, ie if you bound any of the keys b,i,n,d,-,r,#s by accident. Or use sh shell to edit .inputrc (though that didnt work in my case)

Comment: I tried bash 4.2 and 4.4 versions. `set -o emacs' can not reset key bindings in both.

Answer (score 2):

Try [xmodmap](http://www.xfree86.org/4.2.0/xmodmap.1.html); the following command will show you the current key bindings:

`xmodmap -pke`

Comment: `xmodmap` has a vastly different function than the one being referred to in the question.

Comment: It's far too vague to say that.  Thanks anyway.

Comment: I just reread the question and yes, you're correct (I misread the question).  But: if it's not readline bash key bindings causing this, xmodmap is a reasonable place to look.  Thanks.